# how to know which installed devices has internet connection in WINPCAP?

Tags: c++, network-programming, winpcap

i have known that winpcap library enabled a person to obtain advanced information about installed devices...

given all the networking devices found in the computer, how will i know which one of this has an internet connection?!

thanks:)

Comment: Why does it have to only be one?

Comment: You could try pinging a known URL through the device. If it's up, you have internet access.

Answer (score 1):

You typically don't care about this. Normally you just ask the network stack to make a connection, and don't worry about details.

However, each "device" will have its own IP address. You can request the network stack to use this IP address when making a connection.

Now, to figure which devices have an intenet connection, iterate over all of them, obtain their IP address, and try to create a connection from that originating IP to a destination IP on the Internet. Typically you already know such a destination IP, e.g. your companies webserver.

Answer (score 1):

GetAdaptersInfo() will give you a list of all network adapters installed in a form that you can then use in GetIfEntry(). This latter function will tell you the operational status of an adapter, so you can at least tell if the adapter is plugged into a live hub/switch/router.

If you are particularly interested in IP connectivity, you could look to see if a default gateway is configured for that interface. Don't forget you might have to support IPv6 as well as IP4 if you try this.

Correlating the network adapters found by GetAdaptersInfo() with those found by pcap_findalldevs() is left as an exercise for the reader. I don't remember the details but it was fairly obvious.